# http only cookies is not sent in ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jakarta-ee, cookies

We are having two project for a single application.

Project in abc.com will have all the UI files(HTML, JSP, CSS, javascript:Spring-boot)

Project in xyz.com will have all the back end files(java:Spring-boot)

So, when we do login the token cookie(HTTP only) will be save in the abc.com's browse as domain as **abc** and path as **/**.

But when I try to make ajax call to xyz.com from abc.com's browser, the HTTP only cookie is not sending.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true

});
```

Here is ajax set up and did I miss to specify anything in server side of abc.com or xyz.com?